# Registry path for TFS2010 custom checkin policy?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

how can I register a custom check-in policy for VS2010/TFS2010?

For 2008 it was the following path:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies

But for 2010 the path ends after "TeamFoundation", even though I should already have some registered policies from the Power Tools.

I was only able to find this MSDN Blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx

But there he only shows how to register with the VSIX pkgdef file (which doesn't work completly for me). I am able to add the policy in VS2010, but I get an "assembly not registered" error if I try it:
[image]

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/974862/Office/checkin_error.JPG

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the MSDN forums:

> Start Regedit.exe and locate the
>   following key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin
>   Policies (TFS2010)  The registered
>   policies are listed in the right pane.
>   Right-click in the right-hand pane,
>   point to New, and then click String
>   Value. Type the name of your custom
>   policy dynamic link library (DLL),
>   without the DLL extension;
>   CheckForCommentsPolicy in the above
>   example. Important: The new string
>   name must match your DLL filename
>   exactly, without the DLL extension.
>   Double-click the new string value and
>   set its value to the fully qualified
>   path and filename to the .dll
>   containing your custom policy.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsadmin/thread/490f393c-8a37-40ba-aef8-f95b5d736489